# Caching 404s - NGINX or Varnished?

Tags: caching, nginx, http-status-code-404, varnish

I'm looking for a solution to cache 404s in long term (a few days/weeks) on the webserver. My current setup is NGINX with memcached_pass proxy and PHP-FPM to deliver uncached pages (PHP also writes the contents to memcached).
The crawlers all around the web seem to like my pages and generate a few thousand 404 requests a day. All of them hit PHP directly since I can't cache 404 response header informations together with the contents in memcached, hence the memcached_pass lookup always fails.

How can I cache all those requests that return a 404? Is the HTTPProxModule for Nginx what I'm looking for? Or should I rather go for Varnish?

From my current point of view, I'm not keen to change my *entire* setup and drop the memcached_pass directive from nginx. It's pretty neat so far, because php decides wheter a request can(should) be cached in memcached or not. It's also pretty easy to flush the cache when necessary.

My current NGINX configuration file:

```
server {
    listen       80;
            server_name  _;


            gzip  on;
            gzip_http_version 1.0;
            gzip_vary on;
            gzip_comp_level 6;
            gzip_proxied any;
            gzip_types text/plain text/html text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

    location / {
                    gzip  on;
        default_type  "text/html; charset=utf-8";
                    charset         utf-8;
                    add_header  Content-Encoding    gzip;

         if ($request_method = GET)
        {
                expires      max;
                set $memcached_key $http_host$request_uri;
                memcached_pass     127.0.0.1:11211;
                error_page         404 = @fallback;
                #error_page 502 = @fallback;
                break;
        }

        root   /var/www/html/;
        index  index.php index.html;

        if (!-e $request_filename) {
            rewrite  ^/(.*)$  /index.php?q=$1  last;
            break;
        }

    }



    location @fallback {
                    internal;
        root   /var/www/html/;
        index  index.php index.html;

        if (!-e $request_filename) {
            rewrite  ^/(.*)$  /index.php?q=$1  last;
            break;
        }


    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        root   /var/www/html/;
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /var/www/html/$fastcgi_script_name;
                 include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
    }


}
```

An example configuration either for Nginx or Varnish would be great.

Thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

Use the fastcgi_cache_valid directive: http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpFcgiModule#fastcgi_cache_valid